# Another upper bound for the Stirling numbers of the first kind

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, binomial-coefficients, stirling-numbers

It is shown in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3817994/130022) that

$${n \brack n-k}\leq\frac{n^{2k}}{2^kk!}.$$

But a sharper bound seems to be $${n \brack n-k}\leq\frac{n^{k}}{2^k}{n-1 \choose k}.$$

I don't see how to derive this inequality.  Any idea?

Hereafter is some numerical evidence:  this is a representation of the natural logarithm of $f(n,k)$ as a function of $k$ in the range $1\le k \le n-1$, for $n=30$. The red dots are for $f(n,k)={n \brack n-k}$, the black dots for   $f(n,k)=\frac{n^{2k}}{2^kk!}$ and the blue dots for   $f(n,k)=\frac{n^{k}}{2^k}{n-1 \choose k}$.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this proof by induction works:
\begin{align}
{n \brack n-k}
&= (n-1){n-1 \brack n-k}+{n-1\brack n-k-1}
\\&\le (n-1)\frac{(n-1)^{k-1}}{2^{k-1}}\binom{n-2}{k-1}+\frac{(n-1)^k}{2^k}\binom{n-2}{k}
\\&=\frac{(n-1)^k}{2^k}\binom{n-1}{k}\left[\frac{2k}{n-1}+\frac{n-k+1}{n-1}\right]
\\&=\frac{n^k}{2^k}\binom{n-1}{k}\cdot {\frac{(n-1)^k}{\color{blue}{n^k}}\cdot\frac{n+k-1}{n-1}}
\\&\le\frac{n^k}{2^k}\binom{n-1}{k}\cdot {\frac{(n-1)^k}{\color{blue}{(n-1)^k+k(n-1)^{k-1}}}\cdot\frac{n+k-1}{n-1}}
\\&=\frac{n^k}{2^k}\binom{n-1}{k}
\end{align}
To prove that second inequality, expand $n^k=((n-1)+1)^k$ with the binomial theorem, and only keep the first two terms.

Comment: Please check ${n \brack n-k} = (n-1){n-1 \brack k}+{n-1\brack k-1}$
for $n = 8, k = 3$; ${8 \brack 5} = 1960, {7 \brack 3} = 1624, {7 \brack 2} = 1764$. Am I right?

Comment: @RiverLi Oops, transcription error. Updated. It is supposed to be usual recurrence relation for the Stirling numbers of the first kind.

Comment: (+1) It is very nice.